# How to UPDATE a column with MIN() and GROUP BY?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I am trying to update col3 based on the values in col2. But I would like the update to be specific to its unique identifier in col1 (Booking reference).

I have historical data for the past year. Each booking reference is updated every month, so there are 12 values for each unique booking reference in my table.

I am trying to set col3 to show the absolute minimum date, associated with that booking reference. So out of the 12 records for one booking reference, if the earliest start date was 12/03/2018, then it puts that date in col3 for all of the rows associated with that booking reference.

I have had a good look around stackoverflow and into postgres documentation. I understand that this should be done in as an aggregate function, however I have not found a solution that is working.

```
UPDATE table1
SET "col3" = (SELECT MIN("col2")
FROM table1)
```

The above code is following the logic which I thought should work, however it is updating all of the rows with the absolute earliest date, regardless of the booking reference (col1) associated with it.

I understand that GROUP BY might be used to fix this but I have no idea how to correctly include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't really show us the table structure (and using obfuscated names make it even harder to understand), but it sounds as if you need a co-related sub-query

```
update the_table
  set col3 = (select min(col2)
              from the_table t2
              where t2.col1 = the_table.col1);
```

A probably faster solution is to do the aggregation once and use that result for the update:

```
update the_table
   set col3 = t.min_col2
from (
  select t2.col1, min(t2.col2) as min_col2
  from the_table t2
  group by t2.col1
) s 
where s.col1 = the_table.col1;
```

Comment: Thank you horse, the first example worked as expected. I will make note and ensure to give more table structure for any future questions!